catkin make failed
I use Yahboom Rosamaster X3 so i tried to catkin make in my workspace and this happened
CMakeFiles/kcftracker.dir/kcftracker.cpp.o: In function FFTTools::fftd(cv::Mat, bool)': kcftracker.cpp:(.text+0x1f8): multiple definition of FFTTools::fftd(cv::Mat, bool)'
CMakeFiles/kcftracker.dir/.ipynb_checkpoints/kcftracker-checkpoint.cpp.o:kcftracker-checkpoint.cpp:(.text+0x1f8): first defined here
CMakeFiles/kcftracker.dir/kcftracker.cpp.o: In function FFTTools::real(cv::Mat)': kcftracker.cpp:(.text+0x464): multiple definition of FFTTools::real(cv::Mat)'
CMakeFiles/kcftracker.dir/.ipynb_checkpoints/kcftracker-checkpoint.cpp.o:kcftracker-checkpoint.cpp:(.text+0x464): first defined here
CMakeFiles/kcftracker.dir/kcftracker.cpp.o: In function FFTTools::imag(cv::Mat)': kcftracker.cpp:(.text+0x550): multiple definition of FFTTools::imag(cv::Mat)'
CMakeFiles/kcftracker.dir/.ipynb_checkpoints/kcftracker-checkpoint.cpp.o:kcftracker-checkpoint.cpp:(.text+0x550): first defined here
CMakeFiles/kcftracker.dir/kcftracker.cpp.o: In function FFTTools::magnitude(cv::Mat)': kcftracker.cpp:(.text+0x63c): multiple definition of FFTTools::magnitude(cv::Mat)'
CMakeFiles/kcftracker.dir/.ipynb_checkpoints/kcftracker-checkpoint.cpp.o:kcftracker-checkpoint.cpp:(.text+0x63c): first defined here
CMakeFiles/kcftracker.dir/kcftracker.cpp.o: In function FFTTools::complexMultiplication(cv::Mat, cv::Mat)': kcftracker.cpp:(.text+0x844): multiple definition of FFTTools::complexMultiplication(cv::Mat, cv::Mat)'
CMakeFiles/kcftracker.dir/.ipynb_checkpoints/kcftracker-checkpoint.cpp.o:kcftracker-checkpoint.cpp:(.text+0x844): first defined here
CMakeFiles/kcftracker.dir/kcftracker.cpp.o: In function FFTTools::complexDivision(cv::Mat, cv::Mat)': kcftracker.cpp:(.text+0xc80): multiple definition of FFTTools::complexDivision(cv::Mat, cv::Mat)'
CMakeFiles/kcftracker.dir/.ipynb_checkpoints/kcftracker-checkpoint.cpp.o:kcftracker-checkpoint.cpp:(.text+0xc80): first defined here
CMakeFiles/kcftracker.dir/kcftracker.cpp.o: In function FFTTools::rearrange(cv::Mat&)': kcftracker.cpp:(.text+0x1274): multiple definition of FFTTools::rearrange(cv::Mat&)'
CMakeFiles/kcftracker.dir/.ipynb_checkpoints/kcftracker-checkpoint.cpp.o:kcftracker-checkpoint.cpp:(.text+0x1274): first defined here
CMakeFiles/kcftracker.dir/kcftracker.cpp.o: In function FFTTools::normalizedLogTransform(cv::Mat&)': kcftracker.cpp:(.text+0x1550): multiple definition of FFTTools::normalizedLogTransform(cv::Mat&)'
CMakeFiles/kcftracker.dir/.ipynb_checkpoints/kcftracker-checkpoint.cpp.o:kcftracker-checkpoint.cpp:(.text+0x1550): first defined here
CMakeFiles/kcftracker.dir/kcftracker.cpp.o:(.data+0x0): multiple definition of data' CMakeFiles/kcftracker.dir/.ipynb_checkpoints/kcftracker-checkpoint.cpp.o:(.data+0x0): first defined here CMakeFiles/kcftracker.dir/kcftracker.cpp.o: In function KCFTracker::KCFTracker(bool, bool, bool, bool)':
kcftracker.cpp:(.text+0x1654): multiple definition of KCFTracker::KCFTracker(bool, bool, bool, bool)' CMakeFiles/kcftracker.dir/.ipynb_checkpoints/kcftracker-checkpoint.cpp.o:kcftracker-checkpoint.cpp:(.text+0x1654): first defined here CMakeFiles/kcftracker.dir/kcftracker.cpp.o: In function KCFTracker::KCFTracker(bool, bool, bool, bool)':
kcftracker.cpp:(.text+0x1654): multiple definition of KCFTracker::KCFTracker(bool, bool, bool, bool)' CMakeFiles/kcftracker.dir/.ipynb_checkpoints/kcftracker-checkpoint.cpp.o:kcftracker-checkpoint.cpp:(.text+0x1654): first defined here CMakeFiles/kcftracker.dir/kcftracker.cpp.o: In function KCFTracker::init(cv::Rect const&, cv::Mat)':
kcftracker.cpp:(.text+0x1a20): multiple definition of KCFTracker::init(cv::Rect_<int> const&, cv::Mat)' CMakeFiles/kcftracker.dir/.ipynb_checkpoints/kcftracker-checkpoint.cpp.o:kcftracker-checkpoint.cpp:(.text+0x1a20): first defined here CMakeFiles/kcftracker.dir/kcftracker.cpp.o: In function KCFTracker::getFeatures(cv::Mat const&, bool, float)':
kcftracker.cpp:(.text+0x3550): multiple definition of KCFTracker::getFeatures(cv::Mat const&, bool, float)' CMakeFiles/kcftracker.dir/.ipynb_checkpoints/kcftracker-checkpoint.cpp.o:kcftracker-checkpoint.cpp:(.text+0x3550): first defined here CMakeFiles/kcftracker.dir/kcftracker.cpp.o: In function KCFTracker::createGaussianPeak(int, int)':
kcftracker.cpp:(.text+0x3358): multiple definition of KCFTracker::createGaussianPeak(int, int)' CMakeFiles/kcftracker.dir/.ipynb_checkpoints/kcftracker-checkpoint.cpp.o:kcftracker-checkpoint.cpp:(.text+0x3358): first defined here CMakeFiles/kcftracker.dir/kcftracker.cpp.o: In function KCFTracker::train(cv::Mat, float)':
kcftracker.cpp:(.text+0x2670): multiple definition of KCFTracker::train(cv::Mat, float)' CMakeFiles/kcftracker.dir/.ipynb_checkpoints/kcftracker-checkpoint.cpp.o:kcftracker-checkpoint.cpp:(.text+0x2670): first defined here CMakeFiles/kcftracker.dir/kcftracker.cpp.o: In function KCFTracker::update(cv::Mat)':
kcftracker.cpp:(.text+0x1c48): multiple definition of KCFTracker::update(cv::Mat)' CMakeFiles/kcftracker.dir/.ipynb_checkpoints/kcftracker-checkpoint.cpp.o:kcftracker-checkpoint.cpp:(.text+0x1c48): first defined here CMakeFiles/kcftracker.dir/kcftracker.cpp.o: In function KCFTracker::detect(cv::Mat, cv::Mat, float&)':
kcftracker.cpp:(.text+0x22bc): multiple definition of KCFTracker::detect(cv::Mat, cv::Mat, float&)' CMakeFiles/kcftracker.dir/.ipynb_checkpoints/kcftracker-checkpoint.cpp.o:kcftracker-checkpoint.cpp:(.text+0x22bc): first defined here CMakeFiles/kcftracker.dir/kcftracker.cpp.o: In function KCFTracker::gaussianCorrelation(cv::Mat, cv::Mat)':
kcftracker.cpp:(.text+0x29d8): multiple definition of KCFTracker::gaussianCorrelation(cv::Mat, cv::Mat)' CMakeFiles/kcftracker.dir/.ipynb_checkpoints/kcftracker-checkpoint.cpp.o:kcftracker-checkpoint.cpp:(.text+0x29d8): first defined here CMakeFiles/kcftracker.dir/kcftracker.cpp.o: In function KCFTracker::subPixelPeak(float, float, float)':
kcftracker.cpp:(.text+0x43e4): multiple definition of KCFTracker::subPixelPeak(float, float, float)' CMakeFiles/kcftracker.dir/.ipynb_checkpoints/kcftracker-checkpoint.cpp.o:kcftracker-checkpoint.cpp:(.text+0x43e4): first defined here CMakeFiles/kcftracker.dir/kcftracker.cpp.o: In function KCFTracker::createHanningMats()':
kcftracker.cpp:(.text+0x402c): multiple definition of `KCFTracker::createHanningMats()'
CMakeFiles/kcftracker.dir/.ipynb_checkpoints/kcftracker-checkpoint.cpp.o:kcftracker-checkpoint.cpp:(.text+0x402c): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
yahboomcar_astra/include/yahboomcar_astra/CMakeFiles/kcftracker.dir/build.make:205: recipe for target '/home/jetson/yahboomcar_ws/devel/lib/libkcftracker.so' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/jetson/yahboomcar_ws/devel/lib/libkcftracker.so] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:4552: recipe for target 
'yahboomcar_astra/include/yahboomcar_astra/CMakeFiles/kcftracker.dir/all' failed


make[1]: *** 
[yahboomcar_astra/include/yahboomcar_astra/CMakeFiles/kcftracker.dir/al
l] Error 2

make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....

[ 16%] Built target astra_depth_image

[ 17%] Built target pointcloud_mapping

[ 18%] Built target yahboomcar_astra_gencfg

Makefile:140: recipe for target 'all' failed

make: *** [all] Error 2

Invoking "make -j4 -l4" failed
```

